# Computing coordinates from longitude, latitude, speed and heading

Tags: php, math, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last 24 hours now...

Here are the hypothesis :

---

Current longitude (in decimal format): 53.3205556

Current latitude (in decimal format): -1.7297223

Distance traveled in kilometers:  1400km

Heading in degrees: 45°

---

I would like to compute the new coordinates in decimals after 1400 kilometers. Here is my code (in PHP).

```
function calc_position($latitude, $longitude, $distance, $heading){

    $r = 6378;
    // Earth circonference
    // Convert heading in degres to radians
    $bearing = deg2rad($heading); 

    // Compute new latitude and longitude
    $latitude2 =  asin( (sin($latitude) * cos($distance/$r)) + (cos($latitude) * sin($distance/$r) * cos($bearing)) );
    $longitude2 = $longitude + atan2( sin($bearing)*sin($distance/$r)*cos($latitude), cos($distance/$r)-(sin($latitude)*sin($latitude2)) );

    return (object) array(
        'latitude' => $latitude2,
        'longitude' => $longitude2
    );
}
```

Unfortunately the results for new longitude and latitude are wrong (not consistent displayed on a map). I have thoroughly followed [a tutorial HERE](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to try this formula but i can't come across the solution despite this website.

Comment: You should maybe explain a bit further to which axis/plane the 45° are defined.

Comment: Done ! I'm not sure this is decisive information thought.

Comment: You should correct your explanation. If you are at the given coordinates and travel at 45° which is North East, then the angle will either be defined with the equator or the line approx. towards magnetic South (which lies in the North).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. The magnetic north is always the magnetic north on a compass. Even in the south hemisphere, traveling 45° will be NE... How would you have me correct my explanation ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_%28navigation%29

Comment: Magnetic north lies around the Southpole and magnetic south lies around the Northpole. That is why a compass's north pole points towards the Northpole of the earth, because it is attracted towards the magnetic south pole of the earth.

Comment: I see what you mean. Let's keep it simple though and keep as reference what is usually used as reference on a compass and a course.

Comment: Then you should maybe rename it to "Northpole". The word "magnetic" before that will be in general confusing for some peole. I am not trying to lecture you or anything, I am just saying that that you are defining the angle with a line coming from the Northpole and saying it is the magnetic north pole is just wrong.

Comment: No no i'm fine with advice of course ! It just seemed obvious to me. Edited to: "Heading in degrees: 45°" which seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: it's not straightforward.  On a planar surface it's easy, but on a curved surface you need to determine the real direction taken across that surface relative to the E-W and N-S axes, and then take into account what happens near the poles.  In particular, at either pole there's an easy N-S axis but no possible E-W axis.

Comment: Well I'm afraid i can't explain more. All i know in the problem is that the heading i'm taking from start point is 45°. It should be able to compute the position with a distance only with the information given. The formula already written takes in account the earth curve if i'm not mistaken

Comment: The problem is, that the word "heading" is not a standard word (at least none I could find on a quick internet search). Giving an angle is fine, but telling us correctly how you define the angle is needed.

Comment: @RomainBruckert the haversine formula is insufficient.  It tells you the distance between two points, but does not tell you the heading/bearing that you must take to get from one to the other.  In fact, over a "great circle" course ones true heading will vary continuously.

Comment: Heading = course. In navigation, a vehicle's course is the angle that the intended path of the vehicle makes with a fixed reference object (typically true north). Typically course is measured in degrees from 0° clockwise to 360° in compass convention (0° being north, 90° being east). Course is customarily expressed in three digits, using preliminary zeros if needed, e.g. 058°.

Comment: @Alnitak i know it is not sufficient please review the link, this might help to understand what i'v done : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: ah, you're using that formula further down the page.  Did you remember to convert the initial lat/long to radians, and the resulting lat/long back to degrees?

Comment: This is actually (i think, my mistake!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you did it outside this function, you also need to convert the initial lat/long to radians, and the result of your formulae back to degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves from a few years ago, you need something called the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in order to solve this, assuming you're using WGS84 coordinates.

Comment: Yes, this is mentioned in the link that i gave in my post. Did not help. I'not a math guru but i'm pretty sure my formula is already a variant from the haversine forumla (computing distance between 2 points).

Comment: You are right it is a mistake... now corrected. It actually even deserves a vote up cause the Haversine formula might help others i think

Comment: ohhh and now i think there is a bug if i try to vote up it votes down... ??

Comment: You can only vote once, down or up (and then undo it any number of times)